STM32CubeIDE crashes - Problem: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
I'm using MacOS and I'm trying to build the default code on main.c on the STM32CubeIDE which is below:
#include <stdint.h>

#if !defined(__SOFT_FP__) && defined(__ARM_FP)
  #warning "FPU is not initialized, but the project is compiling for an FPU. Please initialize the FPU before use."
#endif

int main(void)
{
    /* Loop forever */
    for(;;);
}

But I'm getting the following error:
22:10:25 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project 001HelloWorld **** make -j7 all  "make -j7 all" terminated with exit code -1. Build might be incomplete.
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x18:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000004e25000-0000000004e29000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /Applications/STM32CubeIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/STM32CubeIDE

Application Specific Information:
crashed on child side of fork pre-exec

Apparently it's trying to access an invalid memory location? Any help is greatly appreciated in fixing it. Here's a bigger screenshot if it helps:


Is this a windows version running inside a virtual machine in you mac?

I'm using MacOS (I also downloaded the MacOS version of this app)

None of the tags is relevant. It is not related to MCUs, stm32. embedded or C. IMO this question is off-topic

The question is literally from a MCU course about Embedded C, I'm using the STM32F407VG MCU and the STM32CubeIDE

Microcontroller-specific programming questions are fine and perfectly on-topic. Including programming tool questions that can reasonably only be answered by an embedded systems programmer. Similarly, troubleshooting issues in some EDA tool would be on-topic too.


Any help is greatly appreciated in fixing it.

You can't be expected to fix it, because it is a crash within the IDE itself. IDEs should not crash no matter what the user is doing (short of writing an IDE extension that crashes - that's not the case here). So, you've run into an IDE bug, and a bad one too.

Apparently it's trying to access an invalid memory location?

I agree. Apparently the IDE (not you, and not your code!) is trying to access an invalid memory location.
The developers of STMCube IDE must fix their [expletive deleted].

How this "answer" can help the OP. You answer an off-topic question which should be closed as an off-top

The answer helped. It's not off-topic and answered the question directly.
